# First iteration of WHILE loop runs out of memory despite manual reconstruction of query succeeding

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, out-of-memory

Environment: SQL Server 2019 (v15).

I have a large query that uses too much space when run as a single `SELECT` statement. When I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'.

However, the problem breaks down naturally into a dozen or so pieces, so I wrote a `WHILE` loop to iterate through each piece and insert into a results table. Unfortunately, the first iteration of the `WHILE` loop also returns the same memory error. All the `WHILE` loop is doing is changing a few values in the `WHERE` clause.

The key thing confusing me here, is that when I manually run one iteration of the `INSERT` statement, absent all looping logic, it works perfectly.

Manually coding the first iteration to use the first `institution_name` just works, so I don't think the joins here are going wrong and causing the memory error.

```
WITH my_cte AS 
(
    SELECT [columns]
    FROM mytable a
    INNER JOIN bigtable b ON a.institution_name = b.institution_name
                          AND a.personID = b.personID
    WHERE a.institution_name = 'ABC'
      AND b.institution_name = 'ABC'
)
INSERT INTO results (personID, institution_name, ...)
SELECT personID, institution_name, [some aggregations]
FROM my_cte
GROUP BY personID, institution_name;
```

The version with the `WHILE` loop fails. I need to run the query with different values for `institution_name`.

Here I show three different values but even just the first iteration fails.

```
DECLARE @INSTITUTION varchar(10)
DECLARE @COUNTER int
SET @COUNTER = 0
DECLARE @LOOKUP table (temp_val varchar(10), temp_id int)

INSERT INTO @LOOKUP (temp_val, temp_id)
VALUES ('ABC', 1), ('DEF', 2), ('GHI', 3)

WHILE @COUNTER < 3
BEGIN
    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1

    SELECT @INSTITUTION = temp_val 
    FROM @LOOKUP 
    WHERE temp_id = @COUNTER;

    WITH my_cte AS 
    (
        SELECT [columns]
        FROM mytable a
        INNER JOIN bigtable b ON a.institution_name = b.institution_name
                              AND a.personID = b.personID
        WHERE a.institution_name = @INSTITUTION
          AND b.institution_name = @INSTITUTION
    )
    INSERT INTO results (personID, institution_name, ...)
    SELECT personID, institution_name, [some aggregations]
    FROM my_cte
    GROUP BY personID, institution_name
END
```

As I write this question, I have quite literally just copy-pasted the insert statement a dozen times, changed the relevant `WHERE` clause, and run it without errors. Could it be some kind of datatype issue where the query can properly subset if a string literal is put in the WHERE column, but the lookup on my temporary table is failing due to the datatype?  I notice that `mytable.institution_name` is `varchar(10)` while `bigtable.institution_name` is `nvarchar(10)`. Setting the temp table to use `nvarchar(10)` didn't fix it either.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to optimize the wrong thing. Instead of breaking the query up to make it smaller why don't you move the tempdb file(s) to a larger storage volume with more free capacity?

Comment: My guess is that it's an issue allocating enough memory/space that it guesses it needs to do the calculations - which is most likely a 'sort' on Institution_Name and PersonId. When specifying a specific institution, it can take better guesses - while if it's a variable, it needs to cope with any option. Is it possible to put indexes on both tables on Institution_Name and PersonID (in the same order for both) and INCLUDE the other columns you need? If not, can you make one or #TempTables with clustered indexes on those fields, populate from the base tables and do the calcualtions that way?

Comment: First you don&#39;t need AND b.institution_name = @INSTITUTION
Second, are you using the Express Edition of SQL Server?
Third, why are you using a CTE here? You can do without...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm not able to touch the configuration of the server.  However, I think I have proof that breaking the query up should work, so I'm really just interested in knowing why it doesn't.

Comment: @seanb With each iteration of the loop using a single specific institution, I was hoping that this would allow it to "take better guesses" like you suggested.  Both tables in the join have an index on the institution name, and a separate index on the playerid.

Comment: @jigga I'm accustomed to using CTE's pretty liberally for code cleanliness and organization.  In this case there's several complex calculations in the CTE that get used dozens of times in the aggregation calculations of the outer query.  I'm using the CTE to define each calculation once and reduce the chance for bugs if I ever have to change it, rather than repeat the calculation in full each time it is used.

Comment: @jigga SOLVED - because I'm specifying the institution name in the WHERE, its unnecessary in the ON portion of the join.  Removing it from the ON made the query work.

Although, it still is mysterious that it still works without this change if I'm not using the WHILE loop.

Comment: Congrats! Well done :)

Comment: You should write an answer yourself and accept it ;)